# Make canvas background transparent - python

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, detection, overlap, tkinter-canvas

So I am making a Frogger game, but have run into a problem. For the collision detection, I am using the following to check if one Tkinter canvas object is overlapping another:

```
canvas.find_overlapping(*canvas.bbox(imageObj))
```

However, I made the background a canvas object as well:

```
background = self.canvas.create_image(0, 0, image = self.imageData["Background"], anchor = "nw")
```

So the program is detecting a collision between the player and an object 24/7. Is there any way around this? I searched SO and tried putting the background in a label, but when I packed the canvas over it the background disappeared (probably because the canvas was covering it).

I can't find a way to make the canvas transparent without making the objects on it transparent as well. I also do not want to calculate the x and y boxes of each object, as that is just cumbersome and unreliable.

If someone could suggest another way, that would be awesome.

Comment: is that an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `find_overlapping` method returns a list of items. Just cycle through the list and ignore the background item.

Comment: @Brian-Oakley Yes, it returns a tuple, `(1, 2)` Can you explain how this works? It's my first time using the method.